# [Sierra]: Mouse scroll

Tags: pdf, mouse, macos, zoom

**Problem**:
When using my mouse, a single scroll-click scrolls several pages.
I have read that this is due to scroll smoothing -
a single scroll actually issues multiple scroll commands:
`tiny` `teeny` `1-line` `teeny` `tiny`
thus the appearance of a *smooth* scroll.

If this is the case, then when in single-page view,
each scroll moves a full-page increment.

Is there a way to disable this?
I requested help from Logitech,
but they have repeatedly only offered me a new mouse,
rather than a driver fix.

.

I have read several questions regarding mouse scrolling,
and have not found a consistent answer.

**Background**:

I purchased a Logitech M705 "Marathon" mouse.
It worked fine, except that
its auxiliary buttons are not accessible through the default macOS drivers.
To remedy this, I installed the Logitech drivers,
known as LCC (Logitech Control Center).

When I installed LCC,
the auxiliary buttons worked,
but scrolling became terrible.

Scrolling is choppy in most programs,
which is at least passable if clunky,
but there are a special case
where I cannot achieve acceptable usability:

**Full Page View**:

For several .pdf programs (Skim, Preview, Adobe),
I use Full Page (also known as Whole Page or Single Page) view.

In this view, the zoom is set such that one full page is shown.
If a scroll is commanded, the page does not move up or down,
such that one line of the current page disappears and
one line of an adjacent page appears.

Instead, a scroll command moves to the next page completely.
The whole page is always shown in full.

This is not to be confused with Single Page (Continuous) view,
which simply sets the zoom to the level needed to show the whole page,
but still allows partial views of two adjacent pages.

Comment: You might be able to use karabiner elements to avoid using the Logitech drivers.

Answer (score 1):

In system preferences, general, there is a setting where a single click in scroll bar will move forward or backward one page. The other setting moves to region signified by where you click in the scroll bar. This could be several or many pages depending on the size of the document.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not resolve the issue with the scroll wheel on my mouse. I do not want to make use of the scroll bar every time that I want to scroll.